# Freemarker with Resource Bundles - how to avoid escaping apostrophes

Tags: freemarker, resourcebundle

I'm adding a resource bundle to model like this:

```
        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Locale locale = org.apache.commons.lang3.LocaleUtils.toLocale(request.getLanguage());

        BeansWrapper beansWrapper = new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_21).build();

        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("templates/bundles/messages", locale);

        root.put("bundle", new ResourceBundleModel(bundle, beansWrapper));
```

However, my l10n team doesn't want apostrophes (single quotes character) escaped in my templates like:

```
bundle.value = You''re account is ready!
```

Is there anything I can set in my configuration that will output the text as is, avoiding the need to escape the single quotes?

Comment: What escapes them? How is this related to FreeMarker?

Comment: This is putting a resource bundle in the freemarker context. The single quote needs to be escaped by an additional single quote. The translation folks don't like that and want it to be a single quote

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to (must not actually) escape the apostrophe if you don't have `MessageFormat` parameters. For example, if this is your `.properties` file:

```
m1={0}''s house
m2=Foo''s house
m3=Foo's house
```

and this is you template:

```
${bundle.m1}
${bundle.m2}
${bundle.m3}

${bundle('m1', 'Bar')}
```

then this will be the output:

```
{0}''s house
Foo''s house
Foo's house

Bar's house
```

As you can see, the `''` was only necessary in the last version.

Comment: how can I eliminate the need for it entirely?

Comment: That's `java.text.MessageFormat`'s syntax, which is the standard format for `ResourceBundle`-s. If you need a different syntax, you could preprocess the `String` before the `MessageFormat` constructor is called in `freemarker.ext.beans.ResourceBundleModel` (or use something else instead of `MessageFormat`). For that you could copy-paste `ResourceBundleModel` into your own package and modify it, then extend the `ObjectWrapper` you are using so that your model will be used for wrapping `ResourceBundle`-s.